# Insert overwrite data count miss-match in PySpark for every second run

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark (version 2.1.1) shell to run my ETL code.

The last few lines of my PySpark ETL code looks like this:

```
usage_fact = usage_fact_stg.union(gtac_usage).union(gtp_usage).union(upaf_src).repartition("data_date","data_product")

usage_fact.createOrReplaceTempView("usage_fact_staging")

fact = spark.sql("insert overwrite table " + usageWideFactTable + " partition (data_date, data_product) select * from  usage_fact_staging")
```

Now, after last line (having insert overwrite) is executed for the first time then the code runs fine and the output table (usageWideFactTable) is having about 2.4 million rows, which is expected.

If we execute the last line again then I get Error/Warning as shown below and count of output table (usageWideFactTable) is decreased to 0.84 million.

Again if we execute the last line for 3rd time then surprisingly it runs fine and count of output table (usageWideFactTable) is corrected and it comes to be 2.4 million.

And in 4th run, again the Warning/Error comes and count(*) of output table comes to be 0.84 million.

The same above 4 runs on PySpark shell is shown below:

```
>>> fact = spark.sql("insert overwrite table " + usageWideFactTable + " partition (data_date, data_product) select * from  usage_fact_staging")
>>> fact = spark.sql("insert overwrite table " + usageWideFactTable + " partition (data_date, data_product) select * from  usage_fact_staging")
18/04/20 08:41:59 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
18/04/20 08:41:59 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
>>> fact = spark.sql("insert overwrite table " + usageWideFactTable + " partition (data_date, data_product) select * from  usage_fact_staging")
>>> fact = spark.sql("insert overwrite table " + usageWideFactTable + " partition (data_date, data_product) select * from  usage_fact_staging")
18/04/20 09:12:17 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
18/04/20 09:12:17 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

I have tried running the same ETL job using Oozie as well but every 2nd oozie run is showing a count mismatch.

The DDL of the output table (usageWideFactTable = datawarehouse.usage_fact) is shown below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `datawarehouse.usage_fact`(
`mcs_session_id` string,
`meeting_id` string,
`session_tracking_id` string,
`session_type` string,
`session_subject` string,
`session_date` string,
`session_start_time` string,
`session_end_time` string,
`session_duration` double,
`product_name` string,
`product_tier` string,
`product_version` string,
`product_build_number` string,
`native_user_id` string,
`native_participant_id` string,
`native_participant_user_id` string,
`participant_name` string,
`participant_email` string,
`participant_type` string,
`participant_start_time` timestamp,
`participant_end_time` timestamp,
`participant_duration` double,
`participant_ip` string,
`participant_city` string,
`participant_state` string,
`participant_country` string,
`participant_end_point` string,
`participant_entry_point` string,
`os_type` string,
`os_ver` string,
`os_locale` string,
`os_architecture` string,
`os_timezone` string,
`model_id` string,
`machine_address` string,
`model_name` string,
`browser` string,
`browser_version` string,
`audio_type` string,
`voip_duration` string,
`pstn_duration` string,
`webcam_duration` string,
`screen_share_duration` string,
`is_chat_used` string,
`is_screenshare_used` string,
`is_dialout_used` string,
`is_webcam_used` string,
`is_webinar_scheduled` string,
`is_webinar_deleted` string,
`is_registrationquestion_create` string,
`is_registrationquestion_modify` string,
`is_registrationquestion_delete` string,
`is_poll_created` string,
`is_poll_modified` string,
`is_poll_deleted` string,
`is_survey_created` string,
`is_survey_deleted` string,
`is_handout_uploaded` string,
`is_handout_deleted` string,
`entrypoint_access_time` string,
`endpoint_access_time` string,
`panel_connect_time` string,
`audio_connect_time` string,
`endpoint_install_time` string,
`endpoint_download_time` string,
`launcher_install_time` string,
`launcher_download_time` string,
`join_time` string,
`likely_to_recommend` string,
`rating_reason` string,
`customer_support` string,
`native_machinename_key` string,
`download_status` string,
`native_plan_key` string,
`useragent` string,
`native_connection_key` string,
`active_time` string,
`csid` string,
`arrival_time` string,
`closed_by` string,
`close_cause` string,
`viewer_ip_address` string,
`viewer_os_type` string,
`viewer_os_ver` string,
`viewer_build` string,
`native_service_account_id` string,
`license_key` string,
`session_id` string,
`session_participant_id` string,
`featureusagefactid` string,
`join_session_fact_id` string,
`responseid` string,
`sf_data_date` string,
`spf_data_date` string,
`fuf_data_date` string,
`jsf_data_date` string,
`nps_data_date` string,
`upaf_data_date` string,
`data_source_name` string,
`data_load_date_time` timestamp)
PARTITIONED BY (
`data_date` string,
`data_product` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'path'='s3://saasdata/datawarehouse/fact/UsageFact/')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://saasdata/datawarehouse/fact/UsageFact/'
```

What might be the possible issue? And how to rectify it? Also, is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is related to your previous one - [PySpark insert overwrite issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49920983/9613318) and boils down to error you experienced before:

> Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from

It is thrown to protect you from data loss, not to make your life harder. There are cases where Spark won't be able to enforce this automatically, but let me repeat point I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49842250/9613318) - never overwrite (fully or partially) data that is used as a source for the pipeline.

- At best it will cause complete data loss (hopefully you have good backup policy).
- At worst it will silently corrupt the data.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Since I am really new to spark (2 days of experience to be exact), can you please write the exact code which I need to write in order to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please let me know the exact code. That will really be helpful ??